# Page not found in Django admin when adding Group or FlatPage

Tags: django, django-admin, django-flatpages

In the admin console, I can add and edit users through the standard auth app and sites through the standard site app, but if I try to add a group, I receive a 404 error that lacks the usual URLconf listing:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/auth/group/add/
You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

There are no groups in the database, and I can visit `http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/auth/group/` and see the empty list just fine.

For flatpages, there are entries in the database, and all SITE_IDs match my settings files. In this case, though, both `http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/flatpages/flatpage/` (which should list them) and `http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/flatpages/flatpage/add/` give 404 errors with no URLconf information given.

The public side of the flatpages does work. All content is served up as expected. The issue is only in the admin console.

Here are the contents of my urls.py file:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from django.conf import settings

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
  (r'^shortener|g|p/', include('charon_sheet.shortener.urls')),
  (r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),
  (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
  (r'^', include('charon_sheet.ghosts.urls')),
)

if settings.DEBUG:
  urlpatterns += patterns('',
    (r'^public/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
      {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes':True }),
  )
```

I have no custom apps that touch the admin interface, and so no admin.py files.

Here's my middleware:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.flatpages.middleware.FlatpageFallbackMiddleware',
)
```

My template context processors:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.core.context_processors.media',
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
    'charon_sheet.context_processors.sharing_url_context_processor',
)
```

And my installed apps:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.flatpages',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'charon_sheet.shortener',
    'charon_sheet.ghosts',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.admindocs',
)
```

I've tried the following:

- Changing the order of the urlpatterns (particularly putting the charon_sheet.ghosts.urls above the admin lines)
- Removing the custom context processor
- Putting the FlatpageFallbackMiddleware at various places in the middleware list
- Putting my apps below the admin apps in the INSTALLED_APPS list
- Clearing the Flatpage database tables
- Reinstalling Django

None of these have changed the errors at all.

This is using Django 1.3 and python 2.6, and is happening both on the standard dev server and through Passenger in a more production-like environment.

I'm running out of ideas to try on this. Any ideas? Here's hoping it's something simple.

Comment: Did you try to remove all instances of charon_sheet from both urls.py and INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: @dan-klasson: 'Fraid so, and it made no difference.

Comment: Have you tried removing FlatpageFallbackMiddleware at all (or commenting it out)? That seems the reason why you don't see url patterns listing and may give a glue to the real error.

Comment: @ilvar: Commenting out the FlattpageFallbackMiddleware doesn't add back in the url patterns, unfortunately, and doesn't change or fix the errors. :-(

Comment: I've come across exactly this just now. Please post if you resolve this issue.

Comment: I'm not surprised, but it was a URL pattern issue. See the answer I've posted below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As expected, this was a URL pattern issue. Here are the contents of the `charon_sheet.shortener.urls` file:

```
urlpatterns = patterns(
  '',
  url(r'shorten/(?P<app_prefix>.*?)/$',
    view    = shorten,
    name    = 'shorten'
    ),
  url(r'(?P<id_hex>[a-fA-F0-9]+)(/)?$',
    view    = expand,
    name    = 'expand'
    )
)
```

The last pattern there was gobbling up certain URLs. Moving the inclusion of `charon_sheet.shortener.urls` file down below the admin pattern solved the issue.